Unable to Access Jupyter Server on WSL Ubuntu from Mac on the Same Network
I have installed a Jupyter server on WSL Ubuntu on my Windows PC. My goal is to access this Jupyter server from my Mac so that I can use the GPU on my PC for TensorFlow.

Here’s my setup:

Server: Jupyter running on WSL Ubuntu on a Windows PC.
Network: Both my Mac and Windows PC are on the same home network.
Access from Windows: I can successfully access the Jupyter server from the host Windows machine using http://localhost:8888.


The problem:
I am unable to access the Jupyter server from my Mac. When I try to connect using http://:8888, the connection fails.

Here’s what I have tried so far:

Verified that my Windows firewall allows connections on tcp port 8888
Ensured that WSL is set to listen on all interfaces by adding the following line to /etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py:

c.ServerApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.ServerApp.port = 8888 
c.ServerApp.open_browser = False  
c.ServerApp.allow_root = True 
c.ServerApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.ServerApp.token = ''
c.ServerApp.disable_check_xsrf = True
c.ServerApp.allow_remote_access = True



Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You can access the server because you’re accessing it through localhost instead of the intranet IP address of the host. You probably should bind the server configuration to the intranet IP address instead of 0.0.0.0

I think it is not safe to bind it to my internet IP @Ramhound

Intranet != Internet; Intranet isn’t routable outside of your network

well, I don't understand what to do now . Can you tell me more clear? @Ramhound

Try binding the server to the intranet address of either the host or the WSL instance, I suspect one will work, I just don’t know which one will work

This link helped me:
https://medium.com/@wuzhenquan/windows-and-wsl-2-setup-for-ssh-remote-access-013955b2f421
Just configured port forwarding on Windows

While we're happy you've found a solution, sharing only a link makes this a "link only answer", which is not a valid answer for this site's purposes. Please add all the relevant information for the solution here, to this post, to make it a complete answer, leaving the link for attribution and further research.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
